# Назначить права на файлы которые будут создаваться будущем

Tags: linux

Есть дирректория, на которую назначены 777 права всем рекурсивно. Но новые файлы что создаются в папке назначаются с более низкими правами. Как сделать, чтобы права назначались изходя из настоящих прав данной дирректории?

Comment: Новые файлы текстовые с правами 644, а вы хотите, чтобы чтобы они стали исполняемыми 777 ?

Comment: @AlexGlebe я думаю, что нужно, чтобы новые файлы создавались с 666, причём чтобы это зависело не от создающего пользователя, а именно от родительского каталога.

Comment: Почитайте в сторону umask и setfacl. Сознательно не даю готовых рецептов, т.к. вы очевидным образом собираетесь играть с огнём.

Comment: Вы решаете проблему [молотка](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-xy/795#795). Переформулируйте свой вопрос, чтобы решить свою проблему правильно.

Answer (score 2):

```
umask 000
```

Означает, что любой пользователь будет иметь права на чтение, запись и выполнение для всех вновь создаваемых файлов.

вычислить значение umask, просто вычтите требуемые разрешения из разрешения по умолчанию

Comment: Нет, если пользователи работают не с консоли, а подрубили тем или способом файлы себе куда-то. ftp, sshfs, ...